# Are there infinitely many Poulet numbers of the form $(2\cdot x^2+1)\cdot (2\cdot y^2+1)$?

Tags: number-theory

Are there infinitely many Poulet numbers of the form $(2\cdot x^2+1)\cdot (2\cdot y^2+1)$, with $x,y \in\mathbb N$?

Has this some implication?

The examples I found are: $1387$ and $23001$.

Comment: Some more examples are
$$ 206601, 422659, 1827001, 3116107, 7295851, 8646121, 15124969, 18985627, 19471033, 23054601, 26886817, 77817979, 170853211, 207477001, 303639337, 466679251, 644051001$$

Comment: Is It Worth an Oeis sequence?

Comment: Yes, certainly.

Comment: @RobertIsrael why?

Comment: Why not?  It looks like an interesting question. Also possibly of interest: it looks like many of these examples have $y = 2x$.  $(2 x^2+1)(8 x^2 + 1)$ is a Poulet number for $x = 3, 21, 33, 36, 66, 93, 102, 132, 153, 162, 228, 237, 285, 324, 375, 393, 399, 417, 450, 468, 489, 564, 588, 621, 693, 762, 765, 798, 819, 918, 951, 978, \ldots$.

Comment: Is $0$ also allowed ?

Comment: Yes i think yes

Comment: No, for $x = 6264$, $8 x^2 + 1$ is not prime but $(2x^2+1)(8x^2+1)$ is Poulet.
For $x = 7332$, $2 x^2 + 1$ is not prime but $(2x^2+1)(8x^2+1)$ is Poulet.

Comment: @RobertIsrael however many are both primes Is there a reason?

Comment: Most seem to have both prime.  On the other hand, for $x < 500000$ I don't find any where neither $2 x^2+1$ nor $8 x^2+1$ is prime but the product is Poulet.

Comment: @Robert Israel so at least One of two must be prime?

Comment: Up to $x = 2 \cdot 10^6$, I found $14006$ cases where both are prime, one ($6254$) where $2 x^2+1$ is prime but $8x^2+1$ is not, two ($7332$ and $315171$) where $8 x^2+1$ is prime but $2 x^2+1$ is not, none where neither is prime.  I have no explanation for why this should be true.

Comment: I've now extended the search to $x = 10^7$:, with $56023$ where both are prime, one more ($2498430$) where $8x^2+1$ is not prime, one more ($3092400$) where $2x^2+1$ is not prime, and still none where neither is prime.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149479/discussion-between-peppermint-and-robert-israel).